# Is it possible to put steam emoticons into text outside of steam?

Tags: steam

I think the Steam emoticons are pretty cool and would like to use them in other text is this possible?

Comment: Sure, just drag the image to your desktop.

Comment: @Keavon You could flesh out that comment a bit and it would be a perfectly good answer.

Comment: By the way, I tried Keavon's suggestion the other day. It didn't work with the Steam client. But it may work if you are logged into your account through a seperate client and Steam web-page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer: **No**

Just typing the emoticon command on any other forum/chat/whatever will not work. Ever. Unless the forum has gone the extra mile to include the very same emoticons that Steam uses, they just won't recognize them.

Also, as far as I know, there is no "Steam emoticon pack" to easily add them to any system.

**But:**  Steam emoticon are just images. Just like any other image, you can download them off the Steam page. And then you can use them just like any other image (just really small). It'll be quite a hassle, but if you *really, really* want to use them, this might work.

There might be some copyright issues if you add them for an entire forum to use, but I doubt there will be any problems if you just use them in your own messages.